# What is the difference between 'toString' and 'as String' in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I want to get View's text. So I check that view was TextView, and used `v.text`.
In this situation, `v.text` is `Charsequence!`. and I try to change `v.text` to String. I got two situation, `v.text.toString` and `v.text as String`. What are they difference?

```
override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        when(v) {
            is TextView -> {
                Log.d("v.text", v.text)
                // v.text is Charsequence but msg need String
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Since this question involves `as String`, it is not a duplicate of that question IMO.

Comment: Yeah, this isn't a duplicate question.

Comment: why my questions is duplicate??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`v.text as String` means "force-cast `v.text` to a `String`". This will crash your app if `v.text` happens to be some other kind of `CharSequence` than `String`, e.g. `SpannedString`. Even though it will work in many cases since `v.text` often is a `String`, it is not what you should use.

`v.text.toString()` means "call the `toString` method on the `v.text` object". This will return a `String` representation of the object, and is what you should use in this case.

Here is some sample code to demonstrate the difference:

```
v?.text = SpannedString("spanned string")

// Will print "v.text  : spanned string" to logcat
Log.d("v.text", v?.text.toString())

// Will crash with java.lang.ClassCastException: android.text.SpannedString cannot be cast to java.lang.String
Log.d("v.text", v?.text as String)
```

Answer (score 2):

`toString()` is conversation from `Some` type to `String` type.

`as String` is unsafe casting that  might cause `ClassCastException`.